# What am I doing wrong when I am doing a search by relation?

Tags: yii2

I have `Car` model with relation to `Brand` model by `brand-id`:

```
public function getBrand()  {
return $this->hasOne(Brand::className(), [
  'id' => 'brand_id'
]);
}
```

**Brand** model has **name** field.
And i want to search by this field. I do this:

```
$query->joinWith('brand');
   $query->orFilterWhere([
  'like', 'brand.name', '%'.$this->company.'%', false
]);
```

Searching by `company` field.

Brand model table_name is **car_brand**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
$query->joinWith(['brand' => function ($q) {
        $q->where('tbl_brand.name LIKE "%' . $this->company . '%"');
 }]);
```